# Can't access property from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple property for pageTitle but I cannot seem to access it from the content page.

```
public partial class admin_themes_BackEnd_blank : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    public string pageTitle { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
}
```

Then I am using the following to try and get the property in the content page I am using the variable Master.pageTitle but I can't view it in the intellesne to select it even though I have build it ?

Comment: that is not what im aasking i wanting to set custom properties here

Comment: You need  to cast the Master property to class: (this.Master as admin_themes_BackEnd_blank).pageTitle = "title of the page"

Comment: is their no way of getting it like .net built in properties to save having to do that making a cms at min